# Using Manifest correctly

Tags: word-usage, sentence

Can I use the verb manifest in the following sentence?

> We would quickly learn that obstacles can manifest in any neighborhood.

Google's Definition:

> display or show (a quality or feeling) by one's acts or appearance;
> demonstrate.
>
> *"Ray manifested signs of severe depression"*
>
> synonyms:    display, show, exhibit, demonstrate, betray, present,
> reveal; formalevince
>
> *"she manifested signs of depression"*

Thanks.

Comment: (Not knowing the context) I'd say yes, you can use it that way.

Comment: *manifest* is essentially a transitive verb and requires another noun, including *itself*, *themselves* etc., as you have correctly found from Google. Use the phrase *obstacles can manifest themselves* instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it should not be used this way. As you pointed out, [*manifest*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/manifest) is a verb meaning display or show. Synonyms are: display, show, exhibit, demonstrate, betray, present, reveal.

Substituting two synonyms, does your sentence make sense to you?

> We would quickly learn that obstacles can reveal in any neighborhood.
>   We would quickly learn that obstacles can display in any neighborhood.

They do not make sense to me. The verb *manifest* is a transitive verb that needs a direct object. Something usually manifests something else.

> Subsequent arguments and destructive forces typically [*manifest*](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/manifest) themselves downstream.

Perhaps you want the word *manifested*. Like *revealed* and *shown*, obstacles can be manifested.

> We would quickly learn that obstacles can be revealed/be manifested in any neighborhood.

Even though this is a grammatically correct, I would not state something in this manner.

Comment: What is wrong with ***manifest itself/themselves***? Is that not just the answer? (Removed down vote when seeing ***themselves***)